# 'nohup mycommand &' via Java code

Tags: java, bash, ssh, nohup

I am trying to run the following command using Ganymed-SSH2 (ch.ethz.ssh2):

```
nohup sudo mycommand &
```

It works when I run directly from command line, but nothing happens when I run it using the Java code below.

```
Connection connection = new Connection(server);
connection.connect();

if (!connection.authenticateWithPassword(userName, password)) {
throw new IOException("Failed to authenticate with user " + userName + "on host: " + connection.getHostname());
    }

Session session = connection.openSession();
session.requestDumbPTY();

session.execCommand("nohup sudo mycommand &");

session.close();
connection.close();
```

The command works via the `execCommand()` method if I exclude the `&` (but this won't give me my required results), but nothing happens with `&` there.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

(Note: sudo does not require a password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a good hint to solve this issue reading the [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) wikipedia page. Combine nohup and ssh require stdin / std[out|err] to be redirected.

If your server doesn't have `Defaults requiretty` in `/etc/sudoers` you can simply use:

```
sess.execCommand("nohup sudo <yourCommand> 2>&1 >nohup.out </dev/null &");
```

Entire code:

```
import ch.ethz.ssh2.*

String hostname    = "localhost";
String username    = "gsus";
File   keyfile     = new File("/home/gsus/.ssh/id_rsa");
String keyfilePass = "";

try {
  Connection conn = new Connection(hostname);
  conn.connect();

  boolean isAuthenticated=conn.authenticateWithPublicKey(username,keyfile,keyfilePass);
  if (isAuthenticated == false)
    throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");

  Session sess=conn.openSession();
  //Don't use this
  //sess.requestDumbPTY();

  sess.execCommand("nohup sudo ping -c 100 www.yahoo.com 2>&1 >nohup.out </dev/null &");

  sess.close();
  conn.close();
}
catch (  IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace(System.err);
  System.exit(2);
}
```

If instead your server `/etc/sudoers` file contains `Defaults requiretty` (@user5222688) you have to switch using `session.startShell()`

```
import ch.ethz.ssh2.*

String hostname    = "localhost";
String username    = "gsus";
File   keyfile     = new File("/home/gsus/.ssh/id_rsa");
String keyfilePass = "";

try {
  Connection conn = new Connection(hostname);
  conn.connect();

  boolean isAuthenticated=conn.authenticateWithPublicKey(username,keyfile,keyfilePass);
  if (isAuthenticated == false)
    throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");

  Session sess=conn.openSession();
  sess.requestPTY("xterm");
  sess.startShell();

  InputStream    stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());
  BufferedReader input  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
  OutputStream   out    = sess.getStdin();
  out.write("nohup sudo <yourCommand> 2>&1 >nohup.out </dev/null &\n".getBytes());
  out.flush();

  while (!input.readLine().contains("stderr")) {
    //Simply move on the stdout of the shell till our command is returned
  }

  sess.close();
  conn.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace(System.err);
  System.exit(2);
}
```

Comment: Getting closer... but I am getting this in my stderr; `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Comment: Try to remove ``Defaults requiretty`` from /etc/sudoers of the server (``sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers``)

Comment: @user5222688 i've updated my answer also for environments with a sudo requiring a tty

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer: if it's been useful to you consider upvoting